# click event not working with form plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, forms, submit

i am using jquery form plugin to upload the images without page reload but it seems that it is not possible to add a click function.i dont know what im doing wrong?

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var options = {  
    url:'img_handler.php',
    type:'POST', 
    success:function(data) {
        //all the events are handeled properly
    } 
};  
$(".post_the_img-sing").click(function () {///the probem is over here 
$('#post_image_to_stream-single').ajaxForm(options);
});
});
```

**NOTE:**its not possible for me to have the `.post_the_img_sing` button within the form

---

**UPDATE:**found out that i could use a submit button which is hidden then just add a click event to the div `.post_the_img_sing`

Comment: is that a dynamic element?

Comment: To add onto what @AnoopJoshi asked, if that is a dynamic content, you would need use `$(document).on("click", ".post_the_img-sing", function() { //code });`

Comment: no it does not change in any way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me, as far as this code goes... Have you checked the class names? Because in your code you have `.post_the_img-sing` but then you have written `.post_the_img_sing`...